# How would I encapsulate a mergesort program for general customer use in C++?

Tags: c++, encapsulation, mergesort

I currently have a mergesort that accepts a list of ints and makes an array out of them, then sorts them, and prints out the sorted array. Currently all of the code is in a single .cpp file.

What is a good way to provide the code to someone who wants to sort an array of user defined objects?

My instincts are to provide a virtual method only file (interface) and require my user to override comparison operators and read/write methods.

Would it be best to move away from arrays and use a linked list?

If this is too vague/subjective then just slap me around and close it. I just wanted some ideas beyond my own.

Comment: The C++ library's `stable_sort<>()` is generally a merge sort (the requirement - besides being stable - is that if there's enough memory to copy the elements into a temporary it has N log N behavior, otherwise it has N (log N)^2 behavior).  It'll work with any container that can provide a random access iterator.  So an array, vector, or deque (or a custom container that can provide such an iterator).

Comment: If your customer is using C++ they already have a sorting algorithm for user defined objects. Is this a real problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use templates to implement the sort and use a pointer array instead of an array of objects ask for a functor that implements the comparison and also provide a default functor which uses `<` operator to do the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it using the standard libraries.

If the customer has their own type they need to define `operator<` for sorting and `operator<<` for printing to an `ostream`:

```
class Type {
    //...
};

bool operator<(const Type& lhs, const Type& rhs) {
    //...
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Type& object) {
    //...
}

vector<Type> originals;
vector<Type> values = originals;

stable_sort(values.begin(), values.end());
copy(values.begin(), values.end(),
     ostream_iterator<Type>(cout, "\n"));
```

Your customer would have to have a very good reason not to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need linked-list.

The simplest solution without digging too much for functors:

```
template <class T, int size>
class MergeSort
{
   T* arr[size];

   MergeSort(T* array[size])
   {
     // ...
   }

   void Sort()
   {
      // The rest is simple...
   }
};
```